# How can I decide about the length of my training and testing data in R in package caret?

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to use the function "CreateDataPartition" and define some training and testing data. But the programm always put the first 2 lines of my table in "training" and all other lines in "testing". I thought changing the percentage from "0.75" to "0.5" would channge something, but it didn´t.

Table:

```
t<-read.csv2("test.csv")
> test
   Spalte1
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        9
10      10
```

First run with p=.75:

```
> inTraining <- createDataPartition(a1, p = .75, list = FALSE)
Warnmeldungen:
1: In createDataPartition(a1, p = 0.75, list = FALSE) :
  Some classes have no records (  ) and these will be ignored
2: In createDataPartition(a1, p = 0.75, list = FALSE) :
  Some classes have a single record (  ) and these will be selected for the sample
> training <- test[ inTraining,]
> testing  <- test[-inTraining,]
> traing
Fehler: Objekt 'traing' nicht gefunden
> training
[1] 1 2
> testing
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Second run with p=.5:

```
> inTraining <- createDataPartition(a1, p = .5, list = FALSE)
Warnmeldungen:
1: In createDataPartition(a1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE) :
  Some classes have no records (  ) and these will be ignored
2: In createDataPartition(a1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE) :
  Some classes have a single record (  ) and these will be selected for the sample
> training <- test[ inTraining,]
> testing  <- test[-inTraining,]
> training
[1] 1 2
> testing
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

> What do I have to change to be able to telle the programm how many lines I want for testing and how many lines I want for training?

Comment: what is `a1` in `createDataPartition(a1...`? you should provide the target variable.

Comment: read the warnings. Some factor levels apparently do not have any records, so relevel your a1 column. Also some classes have only 1 record. That will be difficult to train / test on and might just generate noise. You first might want to investigate your a1 data a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a solution to the *apparent* problem then you could just use base `R` function `sample.int()` to the same end:

```
# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(Spalte1 = 1:10)

# Simple way to partition without any external package:
p <- 0.75
set.seed(1)
inTraining <- sample.int(n = nrow(data),
                         size = floor(p * nrow(data)), 
                         replace = FALSE)
train <- data[inTraining, ]
test <- data[-inTraining, ]
train
3 4 5 7 2 8 9
test
1  6 10
```

Note that here the number of lines in the training data is equal to `floor(p * nrow(data))`.